# MS Flow Excel Business Delete Row Error 409

Tags: excel, office365, delete-row, power-automate, excel-online

I have built an Excel File on Sharepoint that technicians enter data into. Now I am trying to use Power Automate to move old records (rows) to an Archive sheet. I can get the data to copy over to the other sheet just fine but when the flow gets to Delete Row in the non-Archive Sheet it errors out.

When this first happened I found that it didn't work when Excel had a filter so I removed that. It worked for 2 times before the issue came back. Searching around everyone keeps talking about having multiple tables on one sheet. I only have 1 table on a sheet and multiple sheets in the file. I am also using a UID (unique identifier) to make sure the correct row is being deleted. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My only request is that answers focus on Deleting a Row. I have seen many posts for the 409 issue with inserting a row and those are just not helping since they seem to have a common theme of not enough space or effecting another table on the sheet.

[My Flow with the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei8uY.png)

[MS Flow Error Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTu3u.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Your sheet must have multiple tables because that is typical Excel behavior when you have more than one table on a sheet. You would have to either move each table to a different tab, or create an Office Script and delete a sheet row, rather than a table row.

Comment: I swear that there is only one table on each sheet. Like I said it worked twice before the error returned. Also I am really trying to stick to using the MS Flow Delete Row function since many people have access to the spreadsheet. I don't want to run the risk of someone deleting the script on accident.

Comment: no one can delete the script on accident because the script gets stored in one person's OneDrive. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/script-storage#:~:text=Office%20Scripts%20are%20stored%20as,script%20with%20an%20Excel%20workbook.

Comment: Was not aware of that. I am quite familiar with VBA for Excel Desktop. You wouldn't by chance know how to build a script and have flow insert the UID for the script to find and then delete the row it is on? I'm not deleting lines that are always going to be in the same position. If there is not a way to have it function like that then I need the Delete a Row flow tool to work.